# WildFly MDB continues to consume messages after graceful shutdown has initiated

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

When I gracefully shutdown WildFly my MDBs continue to consume messages from our ActiveMQ queue. Then the thread will die to an exception thrown by WildFly. Our current workaround solution is to manually pause the MDBs some minutes before triggering the shutdown of WildFly.

I have the following MDB consuming messages from an ActiveMQ queue:

```java
@ResourceAdapter("activemq")
@MessageDriven(name = "MyMDB", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "my_queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")
})
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@Pool(value = "my-pool")
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message) {
        ...
    }
    
    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        LOG.info("Shutting down MyMDB");
    }
}
```

I have 1000 messages on ActiveMQ queue and trigger WildFly shutdown with graceful command with the jboss-cli.

```
command=:shutdown(timeout=120)
```

*Note: `Enable Graceful Txn Shutdown` in the WildFly EJB submodule is enabled*

WildFly will then start spewing out the following exception until the ActiveMQ queue is empty or the timeout of 120 seconds are reached.

```
AMQ154004: Failed to deliver message: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0421: Invocation cannot proceed as component is shutting down
```

I can also see in my log that my log message `Shutting down MyMDB` is logged before exceptions are thrown, as in WildFly knows it should shutdown.

I suspect that ActiveMQ is redelivering the messages when an exception is thrown from WildFly, because we get this error more than 1000 times. But in the end all messages will be moved to ActiveMQ's DLQ *(Dead Letter Queue)*.

When I read the documentation of graceful shutdown in WildFly, my understanding is that all MDBs should stop consuming, but that does seem to happen.

**Should graceful shutdown of WildFly stop MDBs from consuming from ActiveMQ? If it should, any thought on why it does not in my case?**

- WildFly Version: 16.0.0.Final
- ActiveMQ Artemis Version: 2.6.4
- Java Version: 8

Comment: I think part of the problem might be that you're using `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`. This means that the MDB will *not* start a transaction when consuming a message. Therefore, the `enable-graceful-txn-shutdown` may not actually apply. Does the behavior change if you remove that annotation?

Comment: Have you tried this on the latest version of WildFly? Perhaps there's a bug that's been fixed in the 4 years since 16.0.0.Final was released.

Comment: @JustinBertram Will do some research on 
`@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`. We are working on upgrading, but this is a bigger system/application, so upgrading will take quite some time.